# Swing Class, JLabel appearence unusual

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I noticed something that I considered to be strange it this following code:

```
public class QuestionFour extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea txta1;
    private JTextField txt1;
    private JButton btnSort;
    private JButton btnShuffle;
    private JButton btnReverse;
    private JPanel pnl1;
    private JLabel lbl1;
    private LinkedList linkedList;

    public QuestionFour() {
        super();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(500, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        txt1 = new JTextField(); // 1
        lbl1 = new JLabel("Enter a number: "); // 2
        this.add(lbl1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        QuestionFour ob = new QuestionFour();
    }
}
```

The problem that was occuring was, when I run the code the JLabel does not appear but if I comment the line where typed 1 as a comment, the JLabel appears, which I consider odd since I only instantiate the TextField but don't add it to the JFrame.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, it's an anomaly caused by invocation of `setVisible(true)` outside of UI thread. Try this one:

```
public QuestionFour()
{
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setSize(500, 200);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.txt1 = new JTextField(); // 1
    this.lbl1 = new JLabel("Enter a number: "); // 2
    this.add(this.lbl1);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> setVisible(true));
}
```

Notice: Read/write access to any UI component (such as `JTextField` etc.) must be done within Event Dispatching Thread (UI thread). `SwingUtilities` provides you convenient methods. You should invoke `setVisible()` within EDT, too.

One further problem was that you invoke `setVisible(true)` at the beginning and then add UI components, belatedly. This represents a "write access" to UI components ("you're adding something into the main panel"). Your class constructor doesn't run within EDT, so in this case you had to encapsulate `this.add(this.lbl1)` into the method of `SwingUtilities`. But it's better when you construct your entire UI first and then finally set it visible.

For more information about the Swing library and thread-safety take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html